# how to pass angular 2 $scope variables into the Node.js server

Tags: angular2-forms

I got more answers from angular 1.0. But no suitable answer for Angular 2. I am using mysql for the database.
I want to pass inputs from this form to nodejs server.

errors are,
1. file: 'file:///c%3A/Users/acer/Desktop/Project/charity/src/app/tasks/tasks.components.ts'
severity: 'Error'
message: 'Parameter 'event' implicitly has an 'any' type.'
source: 'ts'

2. file: 'file:///c%3A/Users/acer/Desktop/Project/charity/src/app/http.services.ts'
   severity: 'Error'
   message: 'Parameter 'newTask' implicitly has an 'any' type.'
   at: '17,11'
   source: 'ts'

--task.component.ts--

```
  <div class="container">
        <h2 align="center"><u>Registration Form</u></h2> 
     </div>

     <br>

     <form class="form-control" #userForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="addTask($event)">

         <div class="form-group">
             <label for="first name">First Name</label>
             <input type="text" class="form-control" ngModel name="fname"  required>
         </div>

         <div class="form-group">
             <label for="last name">Last Name</label>
             <input type="text" class="form-control" ngModel name="lname"  required>
         </div>

         <div class="form-group">
             <label for="Age">Age</label>
             <input type="text" class="form-control" ngModel name="age"  required>
         </div>

         <div class="form-group">
             <label for="Address">Address</label>
             <input type="text" class="form-control" ngModel name="address"  required>
         </div>

         <div class="form-group">
             <label for="City">City</label>
             <input type="text" class="form-control" ngModel name="city"  required>
         </div>

         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
     </form>


    --http.service.ts--
    import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
    import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

    @Injectable()

    export class TaskService{
        constructor(private http:Http){
                console.log('Task Service Initialized...');
            }

            getTasks(){
                return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/app/tasks')
                .map(res => res.json());
            }

            addTask(newTask){

            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
addTask(newTask){}
```

to

```
addTask(newTask:any){}
```

since you want to explicitly define the type

Comment: is your server side  implementation is based on nodejs? And are you mentioning about reading the data from the angular component into a db? And since your initial required problem is solved, please edit your question with the now requierd problem statement.So that others can help you as well on that specific topic.Thank you